# SQL is a value in a column a part of a list in another table?

Tags: sql

I believe this question is very simple but in it's so simple I'm not sure how to approach it. I searched for the answer but the closest I got was something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE user IN ('user1', 'user2', 'user3')
```

Which is not exactly what I need. I guess I don't know how to formulate the question for google. I have a table where ALL users are listed and I have a 2nd table where only users who are admins are listed. I need to run a:

```
Select *
```

on the first table and I guess JOIN it with the 2nd table so that I get one additional column with the value "yes" or "no" depending on if the user exists in the 2nd table.

Comment: Here's a a good example on how joins work. [Coding Horror Venn Diagram](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a left join on your admins table and a case expression in the `select` clause to determine if the row was found in the admins table or not.

You didn't fully describe your tables, but it would look something like this:

```
select u.*,
       case when a.userId is not null then 'yes' else 'no' end as isAdmin
  from users u
  left join admins a
    on a.userId = u.userId
```

Comment: You missed the user IN ('user1', 'user2', 'user3').  I would have just given you a courtesy comment and not down vote.  But pretty sure you down voted me.

Comment: @Paparazzi: I didn't downvote anyone, but no worries.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT u.*, ISNULL(a.user_id,0) AS is_admin 
FROM user u LEFT JOIN admin_user a ON u.user_id=a.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT USERS.*
     , case when a.admin is not null then 'yes' else 'no' end as admin 
FROM USERS
left JOIN admin on users.id = admin.id 
WHERE USERS.user IN ('user1', 'user2', 'user3')
```

Comment: I don't think this addresses the question exactly. The does not actually have a list of users. It was just an exampe